# How do i use OnClick event in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, puppeteer

I am trying to parse a webpage, everything works perfect but OnClick events are not getting fetch from that webpage tried everything but got nowhere. Any help would be highly appreciated

Here is the code

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
        "--no-sandbox",
    ],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1440, height: 600 })
  await page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
        timeout: 0,
  });
await page.evaluate({url}) => {
    let focus: any = document.querySelector(".notion-focusable");
    let onclick = focus.onclick;
    console.log(onclick, 'onclick--------');
}
```

This onclick return undefined although if you goto that exact page for this class you will see the onclick event. Here is the link of the page which i am trying to parse
https://dashing-lift-ece.notion.site/My-Secret-Sauce-2b2e9ccbe75d4210aac7688056e33d0c

Comment: How about including some code so we can actually help you?

Comment: Can you create a code sample that is as minimal as possible that I can run and try to find the issue?

Comment: Please provide more information. What exact click events do you want to capture and what do you use it for? A 2 liner Question does not quietly tell what exact problem you have.

Comment: Any more info about how you want to use this `onClick` event ?

Comment: i want user to go on my parsed website and manually click on buttons. right now it doesn't do anything when you click on buttons

Comment: @FaizanAhmad did you solved it?

Comment: @EmptyBrain nope